# Errno 48 Address already in user when attempting Spotipy auth with Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, spotipy

I'm trying to develop Spotify authentication using Spotipy + Flask but I'm running into this error when attempting to automatically fetch the auth token:

`OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use`

This is the code I'm using on `app.py`:

```
@app.route("/")
def redirect_user_to_oauth():
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,
                           #scope,
                           client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                           redirect_uri='http://localhost:5000')
    return token
```

I've added `http://localhost:5000` and `http://localhost` to the Redirect URIs list at Spotify API Dashboard.

Comment: I think error is on your side. Please confirm whether the port on which you're running your flask app is occupied on your system or not? simply return "Hello World!" from this function to confirm.

Comment: check using ```lsof -i :5000``` .  My guess is server wasn't properly killed or you have something else running